# Switch over Fail over and Auto reconnect in multi instance MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have got few queries regarding **switch over, fail over and auto reconnect** in multi instance MQ. while going through [IBM Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa70150_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.0.1%2F0-20-5-5-2-2) on this.

**Scenarios**

1. Switch Over: Using `endmqm -s <QMGR>`
2. Fail Over : Bringing down the server on which active instance is running.
3. Application : I am running a stand alone Java program which puts messages in the queue.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any difference the way MQ handles the switch over and fail over? From the document I could see, in both the cases locks gets released.
2. Is reconnect happens automatically if the active instance goes down either by switch over or fail over? I have observed while putting the messages through my stand alone application, the moment I fired up the command `endmqm -s <QMGR>` in active instance, my application crashes with

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to
>   send a message to destination 'MYQ'. JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT
>   or MQPUT1; however WebSphere MQ reported an error. Use the linked
>   exception to determine the cause of this error.

But If i restart my application it is connecting to the stand by server (Active after endmqm -s  ) and successfully putting the messages. Is there any way to perform automatic re connection?  If yes, is there any configuration available from MQ or it needs to be done from application level.

3. I have seen in the document it is mentioned

**`Automatic client reconnect is not supported by WebSphere® MQ classes for Java.`**

What does this means?

4. So far I am using plain Java code to test the Multi Instance feature. I want to try the same with `Spring DMLC`. Is multi instance behavior supported with Spring DMLC? If yes, is there any extra configuration/set up required?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From an application perspective both are same. The former is a forced/manual while the later is triggered by the hardware/software host.
2. You can setup automatic reconnect on the application level.
   There are two types of Java applications in MQ.  One is pure Java and uses MQ native java classes (like MQQueueManager, MQQueue). The other one uses JMS API (like ConnectionFactory, Connection, Session, Producer).  From the error, it looks like you are using JMS.  Automatic reconnection is supported in MQ JMS.
   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q017800_.htm?lang=en
   There are several ways to use it. The standard way is to enable it through JMS bindings reference (refer the page above). 
   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111800_.htm?lang=en
   Pay particular attention to CONNECTIONNAMELIST, CLIENTRECONNECTOPTIONS, CLIENTRECONNECTTIMEOUT
3. In pure Java, you have to recreate the MQQueueManager object on receiving a connection broken exception. Its not so trivial as it sounds but you may to look at the exact state of the application especially inflight transactions.
4. Spring has JMS Support.  Not sure if you mean JMS or MQ Java here.  If MQ Java, then I am afraid its not possible. All you can use is the dependency injection.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119450_.htm?lang=en
Setup the connectionfactory with an appropriate connectionnamelist or load it through the bindings file (generated by JMSAdmin) in case of standalone.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear answer. Regarding the re connection on fail over from [IBM Doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508357), I got that we can do it at MQ configuration level. It will be great for me if you could highlight something on this. Once again thanks.

Comment: When you say MQ configuration level is it qmgr init file (mq.ini) or the JMS JNDI bindings configuration?  mq.ini works only for MQI (MQ Interface) applications.  That's C/C++/COBOL using MQ native calls (like MQCONN, MQOPEN, MQPUT, MQPUT1 etc).  JMS JNDI binding configuration file can be generated through JMSAdmin.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614256

Comment: Yes in mq.ini. In this [IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508357), it is mentioned that we can do it in mq.ini. I am not getting how to place the parameters over there.

Comment: The link refers to JMS specific properties (run through JMSAdmin to generate bindings file/ldap).  The one you are after is http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016840_.htm.  Should have Defrecon=YES|QMGR in mqclient.ini.  MQCONNX